# Convert custom type to CGFloat in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, types

I have my own little class:

```
class EPPercent {
    init(_: CGFloat) {

    }
}
```

Now I want to convert an element of this class to CGFloat:

```
var percent: Any = 0
percent = EPPercent(100)
var toCGFloat = CGFloat(percent)
```

This gives an Error:

"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(EPPercent)'"

How do I do this?

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Why are you passing `CGFloat` in `EPPercent` initializer? Are you initializing a property? Is this incomplete code for `EPPercent`?

Comment: Post the whole code of your ```EPPercent``` class. You could just use custom getter and setter of a CGFloat variable.

Comment: @Glenn thats actually the whole code... I just need the EPPercent class to test later on if it is an EPPercent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an `extension` of `CGFloat` and create a custom initializer that accepts an `EPPercent` instance.

```
class EPPercent {
    let value: CGFloat
    init(_ value: CGFloat) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    init(_ percent: EPPercent) {
        self = percent.value
    }
}

var percent = EPPercent(100)
var toCGFloat = CGFloat(percent)
```

Let me know in case you face any issues.

Comment: @swiftlynx if `value` is a `public` property then you can simply access it as `percent.value` instead of doing `CGFloat(percent)`